# yum install not working on cluster without root privileges

Tags: linux, git, cluster-computing, redhat, yum

I am trying to install git locally on a cluster (**Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4**) where I don't have root privileges. It is required that I install some dependencies first so the git website has the following instruction for obtaining these dependencies:

```
$ yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel \
  openssl-devel zlib-devel
```

But when I try this command. I get the following error. I checked my PATH env.Variable and it has /usr/bin  and yum resides at /usr/bin/yum, so I'm not sure why it says no module named yum. I was just wondering how I could fix this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, May 27 2013, 05:35:12) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

Comment: If you run `rpm -V yum` it will reveal that python module yum is missing from your installation. The module in OEL based installation usually reside in `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum` for x86_64 architectures. Even when this gets fixed, you won't be able to install anything without proper privilege.

Comment: is there any other way for me to install a local copy of yum? Or would apt-get be a better option?

Comment: The bigger problem is not with the utility that you use. The problem is that packages that you need to install are written in filesystem that only privileged users can write to. If you have sudo privilege then you can install packages. Some linux distro allows users in group adm and wheel to do administrative tasks. What you need to get are non ditro packages of curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel that can be installed in your home directory. You can then use an tools of your choice to install them. Or you can try downloading the source codes and compiling them.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the permission to install the package via yum for local user on /etc/sudoers files. It works for me.